# A string inside of a struct inside of a class

Tags: c++, string, class, struct

I can't seem to get the following code to compile.  If I replace the all the string references with a char * it will compile and run fine.  I am using Visual Studio 2013.  What am I missing?  I have spent several hours trying to figure this out.

These are some of the compile errors:
Error   1   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'ss'  c:\users\visual studio 2013\projects\class struct test\class struct test\class struct test.cpp  16  1   Class Struct Test

Error   2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users\visual studio 2013\projects\class struct test\class struct test\class struct test.cpp  16  1   Class Struct Test

Thanks in advance.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class test
{
public:
    struct structType
    {
        int int1;
        int int2;
        string ss;
    };

public:
    int getint1();
    int getint2();
    string getString();
    test()
    {
        privateVar.int1 = 5;
        privateVar.int2 = 6;
        privateVar.ss = "This is test string 1";
    };
    ~test(){};

private:
    structType privateVar;
};

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    test t;

    cout << "Int 1:  " << t.getint1() << endl;
    cout << "Int 2:  " << t.getint2() << endl;
    cout << "String:  " << t.getString() << endl;
};

int test::getint1()     { return privateVar.int1;}
int test::getint2()     { return privateVar.int2;}
string test::getString(){ return privateVar.ss; }
```

Comment: `std::string` is inside a namespace, not global. Your code sample could be reduced to just `#include <string> string s;` to demonstrate the same error. Compilers are actually pretty [helpful](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7bbe4c3a4162853f) with this one, too.

Comment: You are have `using namespace std` just before `_tmain`. You can move that to the top of the file, or use `std::string`.

Comment: `string ss;` should be `std::string ss;`

Comment: Thanks.  Moving the namespace statement to the top of the file is what I was missing.  Spent many hours with google to understand this one.

Comment: @user3784804, Alternatively, [take it out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c).

Comment: @user3784804 Avoid this `using namespace std;` statement at all and be explicit (like e.g. `std::string`). This will help to avoid future trouble for you.

Comment: How is this question off topic?  This is a c++ forum is it not?  Sure the example is a little wordy, but off topic?  The problem was a C++ scoping error with string declaration.  I thought that string was global once the header file was included.  I was wrong but I will bet that I am not the last person to make that mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably meant to use the standard library string. This is located in the `std` namespace.  Try this:

```
struct structType {
    int int1;
    int int2;
    std::string ss;
};
```

Comment: You are correct.  It was a namespace issue.  Chris nailed it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `using namespace std` at the beginning of the block.

Comment: -1 That's not a really good advice in general. It's better to be explicit about namespaces, or have using statements to disambiguate for your local uses (e.g. `using std::cout LocalStdout;`)